# Closing a session when a user navigates away from a site

Tags: php, session

I've got a login script that does not close the session when the user goes to another site or returns to the login page.  My question is, how do I destroy the session when they navigate away from the site or outside of the directory?  Would I need to add a timeout argument when the user starts the session?  Would I need to use cookies instead of session?

**login.php**

```
require("../includes/header.php");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $p_num = $_POST["username"];
        $pwd = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $user_table";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";
            $user_name = "{$row['user_name']}";
            $password = "{$row['password']}";
            $image = "{$row['image']}";
            $email = "{$row['email']}";
            $program = "{$row['program']}";
            $role = "{$row['role']}";

            if(($user_id == $p_num) && ($pwd == $password)){
                $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION["user"] = $user_name;
                $_SESSION["program"] = $program;
                $_SESSION["pass"] = $password;
                $_SESSION["image"] = $image;
                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                $_SESSION["role"] = $role;


                header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
            }
            else{
                header("Refresh: 1; URL=../index.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

**instructor.php**

```
<?php require("../includes/header.php"); ?> 
        <title></title>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">
        <script src="../js/jquery.2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/less-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
                <div id="logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
                <div id="fsi_logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
            </header>

            <div id="main">
                <div id="instructor">
                    <?php
                        echo "<img id=instructor_image src=" .$_SESSION["image"] .">";
                        echo "<h1>" .$_SESSION["user"] ."</h1>";
                        echo "<span><p>" .$_SESSION["program"] ."</p> - <h2>" .$_SESSION["role"] ."</h2></span>";
                        echo "<a href=mailto:" .$_SESSION["email"] .">" .$_SESSION["email"] ."</a>";
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div id="bleg">
                    <h1><a href="../pages/create_scenario.html">BUILD SCENARIO</a></h1>
                    <h1><a href="#">SEARCH SCENARIOS</a></h1>
                    <h1><a href="#">VIEW SCENARIOS</a></h1>
                </div>
<?php require("../includes/footer.html"); ?>
```

**logout.php**

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

**script.js**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("../php/logout.php", "POST", true);
    ajax.send();
})
```

Comment: How do you know when a user navigates away from your site?

Comment: @Jay, As of right now, I don't know.  So would I need to do an if statement which checks for a `header()` value?

Comment: It depends on what constitutes "leaving" @Robert.

Comment: I know if they close the browser that the session ends, but, say the person goes to yahoo or google from my site.  How do I keep them from being able to just hit the back button on their browser and returning to where they left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //Not even sure what the default action does, but oh well
   ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.open("killsession.php","POST",true);
   ajax.send(); 
}
```

killsession.php will of course be where the session is killed

Comment: what is killsession.php?

Comment: That will be replaced with your script where you kill the sessoin

Comment: so, is it a script I write or get from somewhere else?

Comment: So the script just contains the session_destroy function?

Comment: No, it will be a script that you write and have on your server to kill the session. If you have a logout script, you can use that in place of killsession.php. Just make sure you are using the correct location of the request in the `ajax.open()` function;

Comment: well, you'll have to call `session_start()` first. It will be something along the lines of `<?php session_start(); session_unset();session_destroy();?>`

Comment: So it's basically the logout script.  I understand now.  Thank you.

Comment: I added the script as you said, however, I'm still able to return to via the browser's back button.  I'm also getting the annoying popup that asks you to leave the page or stay on the page when you haven't completed a form.  How do I stop that from happening?  I've added the php and js scripts to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Write a jquery/JS event handler for unload doc and send a request to ExpireSession.php expiring the session

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without adding another plugin?

Comment: Nothing reliable that I know of since leaving a page is a client side event - ie, you server has no idea what the browser is doing.  Javascript is not really plugin - you get for free :-)  Even with the solution that I presented, you still have to be smart about it to make sure that you are expiring a session that is moving AWAY from you site rather visiting another page in your site.

Comment: ExpireSession.php isn't a plugin?

Comment: No..it's a php script that you write on the server.  like the KillSession.php in ksealey answer.

Comment: Ok, that's not really answering my question.  What do I put in this script?  Do I just add the session_destroy function to it?  Does it do anything?  I can't reference a ghost script that doesn't exist.  What does this script contain?

Comment: Yes.  Destroy the session when the request comes in.

Answer (score 0):

As said "It depends on what constitutes "leaving""

```
$count = $_SESSION['count'];
    if($count === 1) {
     unset ($_SESSION['count']); 
    }
    else (empty($_SESSION['count'])) {
       $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    }
```